# Object not fading in - fadeIn();

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm facing a problem with a JavaScript + CSS source code I got from a website, it's a "ScrollToTop" button. I already checked some previous posts but non of them seem to solve my problem.

So I've put the JavaScript in a "btop.js" file and the CSS in the "style.css" - main style sheet. Now when I scroll down (away from the top) the button is supposed to appear but it does not. I removed the "display: none;" attribute to check if the script is functioning properly and yes it does. But I don't know why it does not fadeIn. Any help would be appreciated.

The simple code for the button:

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Scroll To Top</a>
```

The CSS:

```
.scrollToTop{
    width:100px; 
    height:130px;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center; 
    background: whiteSmoke;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:fixed;
    top:75px;
    right:40px;
    display:none;
    background: url('arrow_up.png') no-repeat 0px 20px;
}
.scrollToTop:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });


    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Link to js in header:

```
<script src="btop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If needed here's the website where I am trying to implement the code: http://www.areeb-beigh.tk/ (Contains the codes I mentioned above). As you can see the scroll back to top button does not appear in the page (index.html).

Note: I'm just a beginner so please if you can keep it simple :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't included a link to the jQuery library.

Comment: Oops my bad I forgot to mention.. I have added a link in the header of the index.html page. 

<script src="btop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Which verson of JQuery you are using and where you have included it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a thumb rule, this is a jQuery plugin, please add the jQuery library, before the `btop.js` loading.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="btop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I suspect it is because of the previous animation pending. What you might do is:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollToTop').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Since both the fade functions are animations, there might be an animation queue pending. So, adding a `.stop(true, true)` will stop the previous animations and make it work. Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include your jquery library for the code to work.

like this in your html `<head>` element `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`.

It has to be included before `<script src="btop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
 so the script can use the library correctly.

Comment: You mean I have to include the script 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

or the btop.js (already did it in the head). And adding the script mentioned above by you did not fix it.

Comment: Did not fix the issue.

Comment: @AntonioSmoljan *bottom of the page just before the ending body tag* - wrong. Can you please rephrase it to before `btop.js`?

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked your site with dev tools and the issue is absolutely evident.
First off, your site connection is not very stable, let your hosting company know.

The scroll top  logo is not appearing because the jquery script is not running.

Put he following code exactly before the closing body tag element, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/btop.js"></script>
```

I am not sure you have the right path for your btop.js file at all, and without the Jquery before it, i will never run in the first place.

To be sure, i have just inlined the btop script, see here, as i do not have your pics i made the scrolltop text fontsize very large:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/dYYxdG

Et voila, it is working, cheers:-)

Mind you, this will also be the fastest performing way to render the page.

Comment: Already solved the problem.. but thanks for your reply sir ^^!